# ValueChangeListener method not called on my h:selectOneRadio

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, seam

I am little confused about my radio button list in JSF and how it reacts to stuff and I didn't find much help online. Below is the declaration of my radio button list and the method which should be called in case the value of the radio changes:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{AddExpense.selectedTypeExp}" layout="pageDirection" 
                              valueChangeListener="#{AddExpense.changed}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{AddExpense.typeExpList}"/>
    <a:support event="onclick" action="#{AddExpense.typeExpChanged}" immediate="true"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

When I choose a different value, only the `typeExpChanged` is called, but the `AddExpense.changed` method is not called. I think I'm confusing something here, not sure how the changeListener should react... Below is my very simple test method which should be called:

```
public void changed(ValueChangeEvent event){
        System.out.println("In changed event method: "+event.getNewValue());
}
```

Should I change something in the `<a:support>` ?

The reason I have both event and valueChangeListener is because I wanted to test what reacts to my changing the selection. I just need a method to be called with a parameter which tells me the selected value, so I can load something else.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `valueChangeListener` is not a client side event listener. It's a server side event listener. It does not generate any line of HTML/JS/Ajax code and it is triggered by JSF itself when you submit the form to the server and the submitted value is different from the initial model value.

Just keep using Ajax4jsf `<a4j:support>`, it's perfectly fine for your particular functional requirement.

Comment: Yeah, it does work using only the onclick. But now when I print my variable that holds the selected item in the typeExpChanged method (the one reacting to the click), I see the value is still 0 (default) even though I click around on other values...